# Symfony4: routing references another page

Tags: php, symfony, twig

After updating from Symfony 3.4 to 4.4 and verifying the operation, I found that `app_hq_article_trendtag` in input.html.twig refers to another page. The reference destination was B of ArticleController.
As of Symfony 3.4, it worked fine.
Did you make a mistake in the settings? If there is something else to check other than the command
please tell me.

I also changed some code and checked the operation.
Change `@Template("@AppBundle/Hq/Article/index.html.twig")` of ArticleController to another page-> Another page is displayed.
Change `@Template("@AppBundle/Hq/Article/trendTag.html.twig")` of ArticleController to another page-> No change
Change `app_hq_article_trendtag` of input.html.twig to another page-> Another page is displayed.

ArticleController

```php
 * @Route("/hq")
 */
class ArticleController extends BaseArticleController
{
    protected $indexRoute = "app_hq_article_index";

    protected function getInputTemplate($articleType)
    {
        return sprintf("@AppBundle/Hq/%s/input.html.twig", ucfirst($articleType));
    }

    /**
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Route("/article/")
     *
     * @Template("@AppBundle/Hq/Article/index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return parent::indexAction($request);
    }
    /**
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Route("/article/trendtag")
     *
     * @Template("@AppBundle/Hq/Article/trendTag.html.twig")
     */
    public function trendTagAction(Request $request)
    {
        return parent::trendTagAction($request);
    }
```

Brandevent/input.html.twig

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
        <div class="formGroup trendTags" data-prototype="{{ macros.trendTagForm(form.trendTags.vars.prototype)|e }}" data-index="{{ ec_tag_contents|length }}">
            <label>Tag</label>
            <button type="button" class="add btn">Add</button>
            <ul class="trend-tag-list2" {% if not ec_tag_contents|default %} style="display:none"{% endif %} id="trendTagsWrap">
                {% for tag in ec_tag_contents|default %}
                    <li>
                        <div class="tagForm">
                            <div class="input-trendtag-display-name">&nbsp;{{ tag.name }}</div>
                            <div class="input-trendtag-display-term">({{ tag.str_tag_display }}  {{ tag.str_term }})</div>
                            <br>
                            {% for category in tag.categories|split(',') %}
                            <div class="tag-form__category-sticker" name="{{ category }}">{{ category }}</div>
                            {% endfor %}
                            <button class="removeTrendTag"><i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
                        </div>
                        <div id="brandevent_trendTags_{{ loop.index0 }}">
                            <input type="hidden" id="brandevent_trendTags_{{ loop.index0 }}_trendTagId" name="brandevent[trendTags][{{ loop.index0 }}][trendTagId]" required="required" value="{{ tag.tag_id }}">

                        </div>
                    </li>
                {% endfor %}
                {% do form.trendTags.setRendered(true) %}
            </ul>
        </div>

{{ form_end(form) }}

      //Problem part
      {% set q = app.request.query.get("q")|default({}) %}
      {% set trendTagUrl = path("app_hq_article_trendtag", {"q[sex]": q.sex|default(0), "q[brand_id]": q.brand_id|default(), "q[del_flg]": 0}) %}
      <div id="trendTagDialog" title="Tag Select" data-url="{{ trendTagUrl }}">
      </div>
```

Command

```
$ php bin/console debug:router app_hq_article_trendtag
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Property     | Value                                                              |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Route Name   | app_hq_article_trendtag                                   |
| Path         | /admin/hq/article/trendtag                                         |
| Path Regex   | #^/admin/hq/article/trendtag$#sD                                   |
| Host         | ANY                                                                |
| Host Regex   |                                                                    |
| Scheme       | http                                                               |
| Method       | ANY                                                                |
| Requirements | NO CUSTOM                                                          |
| Class        | Symfony\Component\Routing\Route                                    |
| Defaults     | _controller: AppBundle:Hq\Article:trendTag                  |
| Options      | compiler_class: Symfony\Component\Routing\RouteCompiler            |
| Callable     | AppBundle\Controller\Hq\ArticleController::trendTagAction |
+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you change the order of the functions will work fine
when you try to get Route /hq/article/trendtag,it will get the first  /hq/article that find it,so you can change it like the code below
the file is being read from the top, when it finds the route "/article/"  before  `/article/trendtag` even if you want to get `/article/trendtag`, he only considers the `/article/` first part that found it.

```
* @Route("/hq")
 */
class ArticleController extends BaseArticleController
{
    protected $indexRoute = "app_hq_article_index";

    protected function getInputTemplate($articleType)
    {
        return sprintf("@AppBundle/Hq/%s/input.html.twig", ucfirst($articleType));
    }
 /**
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Route("/article/trendtag")
     *
     * @Template("@AppBundle/Hq/Article/trendTag.html.twig")
     */
    public function trendTagAction(Request $request)
    {
        return parent::trendTagAction($request);
    }
    /**
     * @Method("GET")
     * @Route("/article/")
     *
     * @Template("@AppBundle/Hq/Article/index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return parent::indexAction($request);
    }
```

Comment: Consider adding an explanation of why you think changing the order will help in this case.  I suspect you think that changing the route matching order will help but I'm not so sure.  Maybe you tested it?

Comment: When I tried it, it worked fine.
However, I also want to know the reason why it works, so please let me know.

Comment: I'm always happy to help, the file is being read from the top, when it finds the route "/article/"  before  "/article/trendtag" even if you want to get /article/trendtag,he only considers the "/article/" first part that found it.

Comment: Thank you. However, when it was running on Symfony 3.4, it was working even before the order was changed. It became 4.4, and the only thing that changed was to change the link that specifies the twig of Template from the previous format to the current format. This is strange.

Comment: The order explanation is wrong.  /article/trend will not match /article/ regardless of the order.  You can use 'bin/console router:match /article/trend' to verify. 
 The order would only be an issue if you had something like '/article/{whatever}'.  You might try dropping the trailing slash in '/article/' and see if that helps.  Symfony has made some changes to how it handles trailing slashes.  But even making that change seems unlikely to help.